# how do i make an async call reactive in svelte and supabase?

Tags: svelte

i have these on my index page. i'm really finding it difficult to make the data reactive as soon as the data loads on the page. any tips on how to pull this off?

```
    async function getData() {
  
    const { data , error }  = await supabase
    .from('projects')
    .select()
    if (error) throw new Error(error.message)

         return data
    }
```

```
   {#await getData()}
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
              {:then data}
                {#each data as project}
....
```

i tried assigning assigning Data to another variable and iterating over it but didn't work.

Comment: The best way to make an async call reactive in Svelte and Supabase is to use the Svelte store. You can create a store for your data and then use the onMount() lifecycle hook for the component that needs to be reactive to make the async call. Inside the onMount() hook, you can make your async call with Supabase, and then assign the result to the store. The store will then automatically notify any components that are listening for changes to the data and update the UI accordingly.

Comment: i'll be trying it out. thank you!

Comment: I make calls like this all the time and have no trouble with simply assigning the result to a variable, which then reacts on the page. Have you tried declaring the data variable outside the function, with 'let' and assign to it from within the function? I don't use await in the body to call it though, I use a reactive function call in the script. Maybe that's your issue?

Comment: got it to work already. my problem was assigning data from a promise. i used set to get data from an async function. but thanks though

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this, but facing this exact problem and not quite finding the answer in these comments. Anyone have an answer they could put on this question? Sounds like @ginobot found a solution to be happy with.

Comment: create a new writable store like say, posts. then inside the fetching function assign the returned data into the writable store. like  posts.set(data). then loop through posts using the reactive dollar sign {#each $posts as post }